# opa : using dropdown_li in navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, list, opa

I'd like to use dropdown_li into a navbar. The Opa doc says that I should use it inside an WB.List, but I don't see how.

There is not method in the List module that takes xhtml as input. I've tried to used ordered or unordered method, but it fails.

What is the proper use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ex :

```
WBootstrap.Navigation.nav([
  {custom_li=WBootstrap.Navigation.dropdown_li(toggle_html, none, nav_elt_list)}
], false)
```

with :

- toggle_html an xhtml element to use as a toggle,
- and nav_elt_list being a list of http://doc.opalang.org/type/stdlib.widgets.bootstrap/WBootstrap/Navigation/elt